# Display table and table-cell bug in Chrome

Tags: css, css-tables

HTML

```
<div class="circle">
  <div class="content">
      <span><h3>heading</h3><p>slogan goes here</p></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: 20%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #a7cd80;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  overflow: hidden;  
}
.content span{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
 }
h3{
    line-height: 1px;
}
```

This code is working only in firefox but not in chrome etc. Text is displaying as table-cell in Firefox but not in others that is text is centered horizontally and vertically in circle only in firefox.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RRJcr/)

You could see visually this 
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what is the "bug" ?

Comment: text is displaying as table-cell in firefox but not in others that is text is centered horizontally and vertically in circle.

Comment: `<span>` should not be used for layout positioning. Use `<div>` instead.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor see this even using div not working http://jsfiddle.net/RRJcr/4/

Comment: Read my answer please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you have given your `.circle` a width and height of 0, this means that there is actually no space inside the object and so when you give the width and height of the span as 100%, it's actual width and height will be 0

If you give your circle an actual width and height instead of making the shape using padding then it should work

http://jsfiddle.net/pj3u5/

Answer (score 1):

Use `<div>` to style the content as illustrated in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ENsWx/).

Answer (score -1):

you have to use different styles for IE and Chrome. Unfortunately, some styles are represented differently in different browsers.

Comment: Some CSS properties are interpreted differently by different browsers, however in this case (and most others) a cross-browser solution is certainly possible